# Role creation with knexjs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-migration, knex.js, postgresql-9.6

I am new to PostgreSQL and node. I am using knex.js library. I need to create roles and assigned it to each table I created in PostgreSQL. I am not sure how can I achieve it. Is it to be done at the time of table migration? Or can I do it after migration? And if so how can I do it?

Comment: `knex.raw('create user blah password 'blah-blah')` if your knex postgres user has `CREATE ROLE` privs

Comment: What can i do to add this user role privilage to my table?

Answer (score 4):

As others has mentioned, you need to use `knex.raw` and raw SQL statements (in this case postgresql flavor). Knex doesn't have any special APIs supporting setting roles.

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience with knex, but I suppose you can use

```
knex.raw('create user blah password 'blah-blah')
```

to create user. Of course your knex postgres user needs `CREATE ROLE` privs for it.

Assigning permissions on created tables to users might be done same way I suppose, eg:

```
knex.raw('grant select, update on table blah_blah to user blah')
```

this should not require any additional permissions for knex db user, as It creates tables and thus is the owner.